# Can't promote posts

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, graph

Who know how use graph api for promotion posts? I mean feature from next link: 
https://www.facebook.com/help/promote

I should from my app can send a post to some fan page and then able to "Promote" this post.

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/ - you need to apply for access

Comment: @Igy Where in the Facebook documentation is the information about this found?

Comment: My previous comment is almost three years old - the current documentation does explain how to get access though - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

Answer (score 2):

Manually you can promote a post by following these steps

1. Click  at the top right of any Facebook page and choose Account Settings
2. Click Payments in the left column
3. Click View next to Purchase History

To do it via your app, you should have acces to facebook Ads API. Please note that if you want to apply for Ads API Access, you will need to fill form at https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/517221111658494.